# Writing apache beam pCollection to bigquery causes type Error

Tags: google-bigquery, apache-beam

I have a simple beam pipeline, as follows:

```
    with beam.Pipeline() as pipeline:
    output = (
            pipeline
            | 'Read CSV' >> beam.io.ReadFromText('raw_files/myfile.csv',
                                                 skip_header_lines=True)
            | 'Split strings' >> beam.Map(lambda x: x.split(','))
            | 'Convert records to dictionary' >> beam.Map(to_json)
            | beam.io.WriteToBigQuery(project='gcp_project_id',
                                      dataset='datasetID',
                                      table='tableID',
                                      create_disposition=bigquery.CreateDisposition.CREATE_NEVER,
                                      write_disposition=bigquery.WriteDisposition.WRITE_APPEND
                                      )
            )
```

However upon runnning I get a typeError, stating the following:

```
line 2147, in __init__
self.table_reference = bigquery_tools.parse_table_reference(if isinstance(table, 
TableReference):
    TypeError: isinstance() arg 2 must be a type or tuple of types
```

I have tried defining a TableReference object and passing it to the WriteToBigQuery class but still facing the same issue. Am I missing something here? I've been stuck at this step for what feels like forever and I don't know what to do. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Your code seems to be correct, which version of Apache Beam are you using ?
The table_reference param is not mandatory, normally with project, dataset and tables params, it should work.

Comment: Try to upgrade to the latest version of Python Beam sdk, if it's not the case (2.40.0) : https://beam.apache.org/get-started/downloads/

Comment: @MazlumTosun I have the latest version (2.40.0) already. I'm using Pycharm so all the latest packages are being downloaded.

Comment: This is a weird error but are you sure you installed GCP modules when installing Beam ? i.e. pip install apache-beam[gcp]

Answer (score 2):

This probably occurred since you installed Apache Beam without the GCP modules. Please make sure to do following (in a virtual environment).

```
pip install apache-beam[gcp]
```

It's a weird error though so feel free to [file a Github issue](https://beam.apache.org/community/contact-us/) against the Apache Beam project.

Comment: I think you are right and it's the good direction.